# using GetGroupCollectionFromUser operation of web services doesn't work for some users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When I use this operation : `GetGroupCollectionFromUser` as an admin, I get some result back.

But when I login as a normal user, I don't get anything back.

Any ideas? Is this a permission issue?

What permissions do they need to have to run this operation?

What do I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

I believe for it to work for all users, they need to have the Enumerate Permissions permission setting and the Sharepoint groups need to be set to viewable by everyone.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric.
I have enabled the Enumerate Permissions permission setting.But i need to check if the SharePoint groups is viewable by everyone.
Do you mean the groups i'm trying to test on?
Cheers

Comment: Yes, I recall that if the groups are not marked viewable by everyone, you'll get weird http errors when trying to access the groups. Viewable by all is the default, I believe so you should be ok, but double check to make sure.